# CRUD/FLS Enforcement: how to add isAccessible() to the test class for code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, fls, crud

I received the result from security review from Salesforce team and it failed. One of the vulnerability shown in the report was CRUD/FLS Enforcement. The report suggest I use the isAccessible() check before accessing data.

I have a controller that does look up on Contact, Account, and Task object. I added the isAccessible check before selecting from the object. Here is one of the method from the controller (after I added isAccessible check)

```
public String getAllContacts(){
    // Check if the user has read access on the Contact fields
    if (!Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.id.isAccessible() &&
        !Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.phone.isAccessible() &&
        !Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.firstname.isAccessible() &&
        !Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.lastname.isAccessible())
    {
      return '';
    }

    allContactList = [SELECT id, phone, firstname, lastname FROM Contact LIMIT 200];
    return JSON.serialize(allContactList);        
}
```

After adding the check, my code coverage went down to 63%. And I think it is because of the if statement.

How can I include the check for isAccessible in my test class to increase my code coverage?

Here is my test class:

```
@isTest
public class SoftphoneSearchController_test {
    public static testMethod void validateSoftphoneController() {            
       Test.startTest();     
        SoftphoneSearchController objSoftphone = new SoftphoneSearchController();
        list<SoftphoneSearchController> SoftList = new list<SoftphoneSearchController>();
        String name = 'Jon';
        objSoftPhone.contactName = 'Snow';
        objSoftPhone.accountName = 'United';
        objSoftPhone.phoneNumber='5556667778';            

        list<Contact> ct=new list<Contact>();
        objSoftphone.contactList=ct;
        list<Account> Ac=new list<Account>();
        objSoftphone.accountList=Ac;
        list<task> T=new list<task>();
        objSoftphone.commentList=T;
        list<task> Ta=new list<task>();
        objSoftphone.allCommentList=Ta;
        objSoftphone.getAllComments();
        objSoftphone.getAllContacts();
        objSoftphone.getCurrentUserID();
        //objSoftPhone.searchAccounts();
        objSoftPhone.getContactByName(name);    
        objSoftPhone.getContact('1112223333');
        objSoftPhone.getCommentByParam('12345');

        SoftList.add(objSoftPhone);
        //insert SoftList;
        System.assert(SoftList.size() > 0);

      Test.stopTest();
    }


}
```

Currently my code coverage is at 63%. Please advise how can I increase my code coverage.

I have looked at

- https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS
- https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Testing_CRUD_and_FLS_Enforcement

These article doesn't have what I am looking for.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have 2 profiles, one with accessible to all those fields and other will not have access to those fields.

Now, create users based on those profiles and run the testmethods with `System.runAs(user)`

```
public static testMethod void testRunAs() {
      // Setup test data
      // This code runs as the system user
      Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
      User u = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
      EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
      LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
      TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com');

      System.runAs(u) {
         // The following code runs as user 'u' 
         System.debug('Current User: ' + UserInfo.getUserName());
         System.debug('Current Profile: ' + UserInfo.getProfileId()); 
      }
   }
```

Comment: I'm in a similar situation as OP, this is an AppExchange app I'm submitting for review, would this mean I would have to bundle a custom profile with my deployment, specifically for testing something that end users should never have? Is there a way I can create the profile *just* in the test context. I just want to unit test my CRUD/FLS code :(